# Why pop to root does not work in this sample code SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

For the purpose of this question, I have provided minimum sample code to re-create the bug. Just copy/paste it to run.

```swift
import SwiftUI

final class Popper: ObservableObject {
    @Published var shouldProceed: String? = nil
    var id: String
    init(id: String) { self.id = id }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var popper = Popper(id: "ROOT")
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(spacing: 40) {
                Text("You are now in ROOT").font(.largeTitle)
                Text("Tap Here to goto V1").onTapGesture {
                    popper.shouldProceed = "y"
                }.foregroundColor(.blue)
                NavigationLink(destination: V1().environmentObject(popper),
                               tag: "y",
                               selection: $popper.shouldProceed) {
                    EmptyView()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct V1: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var rootPopper: Popper
    @StateObject var v1Popper = Popper(id: "V1")
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 40) {
            Text("You are now in V1").font(.largeTitle)
            Text("Tap Here to pop to root").onTapGesture {
                print("popping to: \(rootPopper.id)")
                rootPopper.shouldProceed = nil
            }.foregroundColor(.red)
            
            Text("Or tap here to go to V2").onTapGesture {
                v1Popper.shouldProceed = "y"
            }.foregroundColor(.blue)
            NavigationLink(destination: V2().environmentObject(v1Popper),
                           tag: "y",
                           selection: $v1Popper.shouldProceed) {
                EmptyView()
            }
            
        }
    }
}

struct V2: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var v1Popper: Popper
    @State var shouldProceed: String? = nil
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 40) {
            Text("You are now in V2").font(.largeTitle)
            Text("Tap Here to pop to V1").onTapGesture {
                print("popping to: \(v1Popper.id)")
                v1Popper.shouldProceed = nil
            }.foregroundColor(.red)
            
            Text("Or Tap here to gotoV3").onTapGesture {
                shouldProceed = "y"
            }.foregroundColor(.blue)
            NavigationLink(destination: V3().environmentObject(v1Popper),
                           tag: "y", selection: $shouldProceed) {
                EmptyView()
            }
            
        }
    }
}

struct V3: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var v1Popper: Popper
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 40) {
            Text("You are now in V3").font(.largeTitle)
            
            Text("Tap Here to pop to V1").onTapGesture {
                print("popping to: \(v1Popper.id)")
                v1Popper.shouldProceed = nil
            }.foregroundColor(.red)
        }
    }
}
```

Question When you get to screen V3, why does it *not* pop to the V1 screen?  All the other pop functions work. It just fails for some reason when it gets to screen V3.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `.isDetailLink(false)` for your links, like

```
NavigationLink(destination: V1().environmentObject(popper),
               tag: "y",
               selection: $popper.shouldProceed) {
    EmptyView()
}.isDetailLink(false)     // << here !!
```

Comment: There is no documentation i see as to why this works. Do you have an explanation?

Comment: is there really no explanation for this anyone?

Comment: @FlowUI.SimpleUITesting.com, if you look for *official answer of why* then there is no one. Empirically this flag affects how internal links stack is constructed - it is either flat (`isDetailLink ==false`), and then all tags are located in one space - so solution works, or non-flat, and then every shown link introduce new tags space, and we observe behavior as in original question.