# SwiftUI - Navigating back to home without nesting?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

In the code below, if I use the links to go back and forth between views A and B, I will end up with nested views as shown in the image. The only way I've found to avoid nesting is to never link to a view where a NavigationView is declared - as it is in ViewA below. My question...is there any way to go back to ViewA without the views nesting?

```
struct ViewA: View {
   var body: some View {
      NavigationView{
        NavigationLink(destination: ViewB()) {
           Text("ViewB")
        }
      }
      .navigationBarTitle("ViewA")
   }
}

struct ViewB: View {
   var body: some View {
       NavigationLink(destination: ViewA()) {
          Text("ViewA")
       }
      .navigationBarTitle("ViewB")
   }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not create `NavigationLink(destination: ViewA())` because it is not back it creates *a new* ViewA. Once you navigate to ViewB, the back button will be create for you automatically.

```
struct ViewA: View {
   var body: some View {
      NavigationView{
        NavigationLink(destination: ViewB()) {
           Text("ViewB")
        }
      }
      .navigationBarTitle("ViewA")
   }
}

struct ViewB: View {
   var body: some View {
      Text("ViewB Pure Content")
         .navigationBarTitle("ViewB")
   }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. My example was as simple as I could make it, but in reality, I might want to get from view C or D back to ViewA. Maybe I could pass a reference to ViewA...

Comment: No, you have to turn off isDetailLink flag. See here for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64051976/why-pop-to-root-does-not-work-in-this-sample-code-swiftui

Comment: I appreciate the help. Unfortunately turning off the isDetail flag doesn't fix my simple example above.

Comment: Your example above is not valid, but it seems my explanation for that is not clear enough.

Comment: You are correct. I’ve been working on this for quite a while. I get now that I was creating new views. I’m not sure how I overlooked that, but thank you. The problem is that every solution I’ve come across seems needlessly complex compared with what used to be done with popToRoot. I’m just looking for the shortest distance between two views and there doesn’t seem to be a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are nesting views because every time you click ViewA/ViewB it creates a new view object. You can add

`@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode`
and call
`presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()`

when the view button gets pressed you dismiss it.